# What do you call this pin holding two metal pieces together

Tags: cabinets, lock, bolts, fastener

I have a cabinet with a locking mechanism that's missing the pin shown in the following image from an identical cabinet. (Looks like a brass pin with a black crest-shaped clip holding it in place.) Can someone let me know what it's called so I know what to ask for.

[image]

Comment: A grooved clevis pin and side-mount external retaining ring (I assume the reverse side of the pin has a rivet head shape). Get a bolt, nut, washer, and some threadlocker instead of trying to match that. Or beg the manufacturer for a replacement.

Comment: See https://www.mcmaster.com/products/pins/pin-type~clevis/end-type~retaining-ring-groove/ if they happen to have the right size.

Comment: Those black retaining clips are also known as "jesus clips" as when they ping off "jesus, where did that go"... :)

Comment: that's an `E clip` ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=e+clip&iax=images&ia=images .... or a `C clip` ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=c+clip&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: @SolarMike  One reason I have a kit with different sizes.

Comment: Ahem... @popham... Answers go below...

Answer (score 1):

If the entire pin has gone missing, then simply replace it with a bolt of similar diameter, and put a washer and lock-nut on the end.
Use a lock-nut so that you don't have to tighten it all the way up (which would prevent the other piece from moving).
An alternative to a lock-nut would be a pair of regular nuts - one tightened against the other.

If it's just the clip on the end that's missing then you can find packs of various size '[E-Clips](https://www.google.com/search?q=E-Clips&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS991US993&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)' at all the usual places.